# USB switch for one device connected to two systems

Tags: usb, switch

I am looking for a USB Switch which allows one device like a keyboard to be connected to 2 systems such as a PC and Laptop and with a button or something you can switch between which system the USB is connected to.

I am looking for one because at work when my break comes in I may want to switch to doing some work on my laptop and I can save a lot of time by setting it up on my desk like another screen and then just switch the keyboard and mouse over to it and back during my break (in case during my break something catastrophic happens and I need to do work - work during my break) and turn my chair around than having to pick it up, move the keyboard and mouse away and ensure the power cable is still going behind the desk so no one trips, and then doing that in reverse.

Comment: Do you have any requirements, i.e USB 3.0, or a budget?

Comment: @RubyJunk no budget apart from "reasonable" in the sense that i wouldn't pay $2k for it (unless it's made from pure gold or comes with a newborn AI). as for USB requirement i can never really tell what the version of USB things like keyboards and mice are. only Harddrives and i generally can stick USB 2 and 3 Hardrives in the same USB Port at home

Comment: All USB is backwards compatible, i.e USB 3.1 works with USB 3.0 which works with USB 2.0 which works with USB 1.0, etc. The only USB type that is not backwards compatible is **USB 3.1 Type C**, but I doubt you are using that, so no worries. Type C is not that common and very new at the moment.

Answer (score 7):

I have never used this, and I have never heard of this brand. However, this came up as one of the first results via a quick search on Google, so here it is:

The [IOGEAR GUS402](https://www.iogear.com/product/GUS402/), a USB **2.0** switch for connecting up to **4** usb devices to **2** different computers.

- MSRP: $50
- Available on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BD8I2OY) for $28

The [IOGEAR GUS404](https://www.iogear.com/product/GUS404/), a USB **2.0** switch for connecting up to **4** usb devices to up to **4** different computers.

- MSRP: $60
- Available on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BD8I3EI) for $40

[image]

Comment: IOGEAR is one of those brands that dips into all the "tiny gadget" markets. It's a generally trustworthy brand in my opinion. I don't doubt this switch in particular would be worth the money.

Answer (score 2):

And, more searching on Google has brought up this

The [SIIG JU-SW0012-S1](http://www.siig.com/usb-3-0-switch-2-to-1.html), a USB **3.0** switch that allows **2** computers to be connected to **1** USB device.

- MSRP: $50
- [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005EHND30): $31

[image]